# Attaching bad payment methods / cards to a customer to simulate failed charges

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=card-numbers#declined-payments

I am trying to simulate failed charges on a customer's stored payment method. In order to do so, I must first attach the bad payment method to a customer's account like so:

```
const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
  'pm_card_visa_chargeDeclined',
  {customer: 'cus_OA4orvnu3Vr6bY'}
);
```

Or I would use the stripe UI portal to enter the card number.

However, neither would work because it would be declined.

But I need it to be attached to test a failed charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 4000000000000341 to simulate this scenario. Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail.